# How can I access unregistered account from another computer?

Tags: support, user-accounts, unregistered-users

I have an unregistered account on one of the stackexchange domains. The problem is, I only get logged in as that account on the PC I used to ask that question. Is it a possibility to transfer this unregistered account (as a cookie file or I don't know what) to another PC, so I can use it from there?

Comment: Why not go back to that computer and register?

Comment: Because I don't like that information about my ALL accounts is exposed to everyone. The second thing is that to have separate accounts I should provide different emails, which is very inconvinient. Say, I'm an experienced programmer, but my english is poor. So I have a good rep. on stackoverflow, but asking some novice question on english.stackexchange. Another example, I want to maintain my great questions/great answers account to be used as a career tool. Also I have some simple/novice questions I would like to get answers to, so I want to have two separate accounts.

Comment: Ummm, register using a different login, and don't associate the accounts. Also, who cares if your rep is lower on the English site. These are Q&A sites, not job boards. ;)

Comment: @jmort253 you're right except that you're not. If I show my account to my potential employer, they will probably review all my questions and they won't be happy if they found me asking really simple questions.

Comment: @jmort253 it's impossible to not to associate the accounts. They're automatically linked together. The only way to work around this is to provide different email adress. So for every "new" account you need new email.

Comment: What kind of people do you work for? My employers don't have time to sit down all day and read every question I've posted on the Internet. They have a business to run. You're being a little too paranoid. And if it really bothers you that much, just do what I said and register the Stack Overflow account using different credentials ;)

Comment: Luckily for you, it's easy to create another email account. ;)

Comment: @jmort253 I'm talking about prospective employers and those who I will search through careers.stackoverflow.com. Those will review all account details thoroughly. My question is not "How to create different account", but how to transfer unregistered account credentials to another machine, so I can use it from there.

Comment: The answer is, you can't. But you're welcome to go snag the cookie from the other machine and try to hack it by copying it into the cookies on your other pc... if you lose the account though, don't say I didn't warn you ;)  Still think you're being a bit too paranoid. No one is going to care if you ask beginner questions somewhere. You're not being hired because you're an all-knowing expert of all knowledge in the universe. ;)

Comment: @jmort253 There are some more intimate stackexchange domains like family, workplace or religious ones. All this information gets exposed if someone knows your account on any other SE domain. And that information may be potentially harmful for your current or future employment. It's like posting everything publicly on facebook.